# Expand variables in variables with a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, scripting

How can I expand a variable in a variable in batch file? This should print `compiler64.exe` instead it prints `PLATFORM%`

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set PLATFORM=X64
set FLAGS_COMPILER_X86=compiler32.exe
set FLAGS_COMPILER_X64=compiler64.exe
set FLAGS=%FLAGS_COMPILER_%PLATFORM%%
echo %FLAGS%
```

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35532216/cmd-piping-echo-to-set-expanding-variables-in-variables/35538235#35538235) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35639223/find-all-ocurences-of-letter-change-to-diffrent-letter/35642840#35642840)...

Comment: This is not the same thing!

Comment: You want this instead: `set FLAGS=!FLAGS_COMPILER_%PLATFORM%!`

Comment: I changed the description that appear at the given link, changed _3 words_ (and the examples) and got this: "If you want to use _another variable_ in a variable name, then you must know that the replacement of variables enclosed in percents by their values is parsed _from left to right_; this mean that: `%FLAGS_COMPILER_%PLATFORM%%` don't give the desired result because it mean: show the value of `%FLAGS_COMPILER_%` variable, followed by `PLATFORM`, etc...

Comment: To solve this problem you must use _Delayed Expansion_, that is, insert `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` command at beginning, enclose other variable in percents, and enclose the original variable in exclamation marks: `!FLAGS_COMPILER_%PLATFORM%!`"   You should learn to read a general description in a way that it adapts to your particular problem.