# Display an asked variable in Batch (variable inside a variable)

Tags: variables, batch-file

Is there any way to ask the user which variable wants to be shown and display it? It should be, ***as a concept***, something like this:

```
@echo off
set "VAR_1=THIS IS VAR_1"
set "VAR_2=THIS IS VAR_2"
set /p "VAR_TO_SHOW=Enter the variable to show: (VAR_1/VAR_2)"
echo %%VAR_TO_SHOW%%
```

So if we are in "echo %%VAR_TO_SHOW%%" if we entered "VAR_1" I would want to look like this:

```
echo %VAR_1%
```

So the output would be "THIS IS VAR_1". Summarizing all what I've said, **I would want to make a variable inside a variable**. How can I make this?

*Another thing I would want to comment is that I've alredy tried "%%!VAR!%%" and "%%VAR%%" without the exclamation marks, but what is displayied is or "%!VAR_TO_SHOW!%" or the same but without (again) the exclamation marks...*

Comment: With the nested `!variable!`, did you use `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion` ?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35993396/expand-variables-in-variables-with-a-batch-file

Comment: ...in batch-file: `call echo %%%VAR_TO_SHOW%%%`; in command prompt: `call echo %%VAR_TO_SHOW%%`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off
set "VAR_1=THIS IS VAR_1"
set "VAR_2=THIS IS VAR_2"
set /p "VAR_TO_SHOW=Enter the variable to show: (VAR_1/VAR_2)"
call echo %%%VAR_TO_SHOW%%%
```

or

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "VAR_1=THIS IS VAR_1"
set "VAR_2=THIS IS VAR_2"
set /p "VAR_TO_SHOW=Enter the variable to show: (VAR_1/VAR_2)"
echo !%VAR_TO_SHOW%!
```

the second way will work faster.

Comment: Thank you a lot!! Thank you, as well, for putting two answers in one! PS: I will take the first one, as I undertand it easier :).