# How to get the env value that itself is a variable?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Suppose I have env variables in windows:

```
IA=C:\a
IB=C:\b
```

now I write a batch script:(named s.bat)

```
@echo off
set var=%1
echo %var%
```

When I run `s.bat IA`,the result is `IA` , but I actually want the result to be `C:\a`. How can I achieve this requirement?

Comment: Use `set var="%IA"`?

Comment: The way to achieve this management is described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35993396/expand-variables-in-variables-with-a-batch-file) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35532216/cmd-piping-echo-to-set-expanding-variables-in-variables/35538235#35538235). A detailed explanation of the method used is given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use delayed expansion or the call trick.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "varname=%1"
echo %varname%
echo !%varname%!  - This works
call echo %%varname%%  - This too
```