# How to loop through hard-coded key-value pairs line by line and parse each pair into key and value?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, keyvaluepair

I am looking for a Windows Batch (Cmd.exe) counterpart of the Unix bash code shown below.  Key-value pairs are given by HereDoc.  The pairs are repeatedly read by the `read` command associated with the `while` command.  `IFS=$';'` defines a semicolon (;) as the delimiter between the key and the value.  The `read` command parses each pair into the variables `ky` and `val`.  The loop body shall do something about the variables `$ky` and `$val`.  Note that values may contain spaces.

```
while IFS=$';' read -r ky val; do
  # Do something about $ky and $val
  echo "$ky - $val"
done < <(cat << EOF
a;P p
b;Q q
c;R r
EOF
)
# OUTPUT
# a - P p
# b - Q q
# c - R r
```

The synopsis of the while-do-done compound command of bash is:

```
while ConditionalCommand; do COMMANDS; done
```

The command statement `read -r ky val` belongs to the ConditionalCommand of `while`.

The list of key-value pairs may be regarded as an associative list.  However, there is no need to create an array, which would occupy memory in addition to the list.

On Cmd.exe, I thought about

```
for %%i in (
a;P p
b;Q q
c;R r
) do (
rem Parse each pair into two variables.
rem Do something about the two variables.
)
```

However, I do not know how to parse each pair, nor how to define the delimiter.

In fact, this batch code does not even work as I expected.  I expected that this batch code would execute the loop body only three times, and that %%i would receive a whole pair (or an entire line) at a time.  However, the loop body is actually executed nine times, and %%i receives only one letter at a time, as the following code reveals.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set n=1
for %%i in (
a;P p
b;Q q
c;R r
) do (
rem Parse each pair into two variables.
rem Do something about the two variables.
echo !n!
echo %%i
set /a n+=1
)
```

The answer by rojo to the question "[Batch: Parse TXT Lines into Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30403022)" (questions/30403022) simulates an associative array.  However, it uses an external file which contains key-value pairs.  I do NOT want to use a file to provide key-value pairs.  I want to hard-code key-value pairs.  And that should be line by line; that is, a line for each pair.  Hence, the list must consist of multiple lines.  I do not want to lay the list on a single long line like

```
a;P pNLb;Q qNLc;R r    # <-- I do not want this
```

The answer by Aacini to the question "[Find ALL Ocurences of Letter change to Diffrent Letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35639223)" (questions/35639223) uses an associative array.  However, I do not need to create an array.  Just a hard-coded associative list is enough for my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Key/Value pairs does not contain any of these character `"?*` then this will do what you want

```
for %%P in (
    "a;P p"
    "b;Q q"
    "c;R r"
) do for /F "tokens=1* delims=;" %%A in ("%%~P") do (
    echo Key: %%A  ** Value: %%B
)
```

each Key/Value pair can be placed in a separate line as shown above or can be placed in one line. It's just a matter of taste, as long as the quoted pair are separated by at least one delimiter like `;,=<space><newLine>` the `FOR` is happy.

Comment: I think the Key or Value should also not contain a ;  or it will be able to delimit the strings correctly

Comment: If the Keys may contain `;` then by the very definition of being a delimiter, `;` can not be used as a delimiter. The Values may contain `;` though (but not start with, as consecutive delimiters will be compressed to one), as `tokens=1*` instructs to pick the first token(Key) and treat the rest, if any, as literals for the next token(Value)